# Does a/b need to be in lowest term in the definition of rational number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition

Also, can an irrational number be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where a and b are **NOT** in the lowest term?

This may seem like a low effort, but the question is simple and I don't want to complicate it further. I try to find answers on the internet, some people define it as $\frac{a}{b}$ in lowest but others don't, and I want to know if defining them in lowest term is just an exception for some proof, and not the rule.

Comment: Which definition of rational numbers do you have in mind? Are you asking whether it is somehow wrong to write about, say, $\frac{16}{64}$?

Comment: An irrational number *cannot* be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, whether or not they are in lowest terms.  A rational number can be so written, multiple ways, such as @JoséCarlosSantos's example of $q=\frac{16}{64}=\frac14=\frac{-25}{-100}$.  Saying that you will write $q$ as $\frac ab$ where  $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers and $b>0$ gives a potentially useful way of writing rationals since each rational has exactly one such representation and each such representation produces one rational

Comment: If for a number $x$ there exists a fraction $a/b$ such that $x=a/b$ then there also exists an irreductible fraction $p/q$ (whether it's the same one or not) such that $x=p/q$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, I was just wondering if there is some instance where an irrational number can be written in p/q form if the p and q are not in the lowest term. I know this seems very obvious that it doesn't exist but I'm quite new to proof, and sometimes, stuff that I thought didn't exist exists turns out to exist. On top of that, some people explicitly state that p and q should be in the lowest term, and I'm wondering if that is just optional .so I decided to make a post about it once and for all. Also thanks to David and Henry for the insights.

Comment: $\frac 32$ and $\frac 64$ are just different representations if the same rational number, almost like $14$ and “quatorze” and  XIV represent the same natural number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Defintion:** $x$ is a rational number if there are two integers $a,b$ s.t. $x=\frac{a}{b}$.

For the first part of your question:

- Every rational $x$ have a **minimal form** $\frac{a}{b}$, namely $x$
  can be viewed as a quotient of two coprimes $a,b$. It can also be
  viewed as $\frac{2a}{2b}$ or $\frac{3a}{3b}$ or...

For the second part of your question:

- If you have a number $x$ s.t. $x=\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b$ wich are not
  comprimes then $x$ is defently a rational number and not irational,
  look at the defintion above.